# How to display the User profile picture at remote web site in provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, user-profile, apps-development

Our application is a SharePoint provider hosted app and we would like to display the user profile picture at our remote web site. We are able to get the user profile URL which requires the read access to the "SharePoint/social/tenant" ( [App permission requests for accessing social features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163864(v=office.15).aspx#bkmk_AppPerms) by using Client API (code would be like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182(v=office.15).aspx#SP15UserProf_codeexample1)).

The challenge we are facing is that the picture won't be displayed at remote web by putting that user profile URL into a IMG tag since there are cross domain access (visit the user profile picture at my site from our remote web site). The solution we are using right now is to download the user profile picture stream from my site, however it would require the read access to the whole content tenent (SharePoint/content/tenant) which is a quite high permission. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you getting the URL to the picture? Once you have that cross domain should not be an issue. Do your viewers have access to the User Photos library?

Comment: yes, we are able to get the URL. Yes, viewer at our web site would be users at SharePoint as well. I would assume that they have access to the User Photos library.

Comment: Yes, they will have access. So I am not clear on what the problem is. You should not have to download the image, just render it in a <IMG> tag.

Comment: thanks @MatthewMcDermott for looking into this. What we found out is that the user profile pictures are protected by authentication. if end user is already logged into the SharePoint at browser and we are able to access his user profile picture by using IMG tag since the image is already cached by browser, however if we want to access other users' picture, the cross domain restriction would kick in and access to that user profile pictures would be redirect for authentication unless that images are already cached and IMG itself doesn't handle the authentication.

Comment: Right, they need to be authenticated by SharePoint. But you could also put the My Site Host in the Browser Trusted Sites list with Group Policy and the authentication would happen without impacting the request, right? Or are your users not part of the domain?

Comment: I tried to put my site host into the IE trusted sites, however I am still not able to access user profile pictures (not cached) at remote site. I somehow didn't find anything in internet about how to use trusted sits to get pass the cross domain restriction, please let me know if you know some good link. I think that user is part of domain, however we are living at the BYOD time, I am not sure that company could use GPO to push this out to those BYOD devices.